# Глобальная переменная, доступная в другом скрипте

Tags: скрипт, jquery, php, переменные

Здравствуйте.

Можно ли создать такую глобальную переменную, допустим, в одном скрипте, которая будет доступна (если будет создана) в другом скрипте? Например, пользователь авторизовался. Имя пользователя = в глобальную переменную. А потом перенаправлять на другую страницу, где выводить в блоке приветствия эту переменную?

Comment: А куки для вашего случая не подойдут?

Comment: setcookie("dvornik-name",$user);

пробую так.. а после авторизации уже на другой странице надо вывести  <h2> Привет, <? echo @$_COOKIE['username']; ?></h2>
только ошибка вылетает..

Comment: `"dvornik-name"`... Ммм, скоро будет очередной бум в интернете - соц. сеть для дворников! С вахтершами и игрой в дурака

Comment: Это просто тестовое задание.

Comment: А это просто сарказм.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Имя пользователя = в глобальную переменную. А потом перенаправлять на другую страницу, где выводить в блоке приветствия эту переменную?

для этого существует механизмы [sessions](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.sessions.php) и [coockie](http://php.su/phphttp/?cookies) (куки крайний вариант).  а чтобы просто сделать глобальную константу существует директива [define](http://php.su/functions/?define)

Comment: сессии помогли) спасибо)